# waiting for dispatch to finish in actions

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I have a function that loads user data from firebase real time database. The function calls the action that loads the data in the main loading screen (in `componentDidMount`). The problem is that the loading page navigates to the main screen before loading is done (data fetch from firebase and dispatch).

The functions that is being called at the beginning of the app run:

```
async componentDidMount(){
....

     if (facebookToken !== null){
        await this.props.loadData();
        this.props.navigation.navigate("MainScreen"); 
....
    }
```

and the action that is being called:

```
export const loadData = () => async dispatch => {

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    dispatch({ type: SAVE_USER, payload: {prop: "uid", value: user.uid}});
    firebase.database().ref(`/users/${user.uid}`)
            .once('value', snapshot => {
              dispatch({type: UPDATE_CREDENTIALS, payload: { prop: "phone", value: snapshot.val().phone}});
              dispatch({type: UPDATE_CREDENTIALS, payload: { prop: "country", value: snapshot.val().country}});
              dispatch({ type: SAVE_USER, payload: {prop: "name", value: snapshot.val().name}});
              dispatch({ type: SAVE_USER, payload: {prop: "fbPicture", value: snapshot.val().photo}});
            })
          }
  });

...
}
```

I can't seem to find the solution that works so that data call is done before it continues to navigate to `MainScreen`

Answer (score 1):

- Define a redux state variable called 'loadInProgress' and initialize it to true.
- Set 'loadInProgress' to false when loading data succeeds ('LOAD_SUCCESS). I am not sure what you want to do if it fails ('LOAD_FAIL')
- In 'render', check 'this.props.loadInProgress' and navigate to the other screen if it is false.
- If you get a 'Cannot update during an existing state transition' error, move this check to componentDidUpdate

Comment: This is a bypass to the solution, unfortunately. I don't want to add more logic. Instead, I'm trying to find a solution that works with await/async or with promises, which I didn't work for me yet.

Answer (score 0):

ok I found a solution :)

I added a `.then` statement to the action call so:

```
async componentDidMount(){
....

 if (facebookToken !== null){
    await this.props.loadData().then(() => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("MainScreen");  })


....
    }
```

and In the action I wrapped the function call with `return new Promise()` and used `resolve()` after all dispatch calls are done :

```
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
       dispatch({ type: SAVE_USER, payload: {prop: "uid", value: user.uid}});
       firebase.database().ref(`/users/${user.uid}`)
                 .once('value', snapshot => {
                   if (snapshot.val() !== null){
                      dispatch({type: UPDATE_CREDENTIALS, payload: { prop: "phone", value: snapshot.val().phone}});
                      dispatch({type: UPDATE_CREDENTIALS, payload: { prop: "country", value: snapshot.val().country}});
                      dispatch({ type: SAVE_USER, payload: {prop: "name", value: snapshot.val().name}});
                      dispatch({ type: SAVE_USER, payload: {prop: "fbPicture", value: snapshot.val().photo}});
                    }
                    resolve();
                });
       });
  })
```